# relation between trace of product and sum of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Given A and B positive definite matrices.

Is there an inequality relation between trace(AB) and trace(A+B) ?

Comment: for symmetric matrices, $tr(AB)=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}b_{ij}$, and $tr(A+B)=\sum_{i}a_{ii}+b_{ii}$.  I'm thinking you could construct a counter example to either inequality direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any interesting linear inequality relating them, just as in the scalar case there's not much relating $xy$ and $x+y$.

There are quadratic inequalities that follow from von Neumann's inequality, such as
$$4\mathrm{tr}(AB) < \mathrm{tr}(A+B)^2,$$
since
$$4\mathrm{tr}(AB) \leq 4\sum_i \lambda_i \mu_i < 4 \sum_{i,j} \lambda_i\mu_j = \left(\sum_i \lambda_i + \mu_i\right)^2 - \left(\sum_i \lambda_i - \mu_i\right)^2 \leq \mathrm{tr}(A+B)^2$$

Comment: In the scalar case, there's the inequality of the arithmetic and geometric means, $\sqrt{xy}\le(x+y)/2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Right, I think that 2 can be made a 4 as well in this case.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Tightened the inequality appropriately.

Comment: The inequality $4tr(AB)$ $\leq$ $tr(A+B)^{2}$ is lower bound for $tr(A+B)$ is there another inequality for the upper bound, i.e. $?? $ $\geq$ $tr(A+B)$